# Limit characters on specific number in a HTML Text with PHP

Tags: php, ckeditor, character, maxlength

I am using the **CKEditor** and I have found/modified a plugin that counts the characters.

I have premium and basic users.
The basic user is limited to 1000 characters and the premium is unlimited, but basic can write full text for preview/tests etc. (it's clients spec, so can't change that).

While I am showing e.g. 1500 of 1000 characters in CKEditor, **I want to save in DB 1500 chars but show only the 1000 of them on text output**.

But strlen and related functions are counting the HTML tags as chars and I don't want this. Also I don't want to strip them, because I will lose the format.

Is there a way to be sure that the limit will be applied but also all the tags will be remain **(in PHP)**??

Thanks...

Comment: "interrupting" some text in the middle of arbitary HTML is non-trivial. First you have to find the text node where you finally reach 1000 text characters, then you have to delete all text nodes in the dom from that point onwards, so that the structure of the HTML document remains valid, but has no more content in it after the cutoff point.

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$theHTML='<h2>Hello!</h2>';
$length = strlen ( strip_tags($theHTML) ); //Should be 6
echo "The non-HTML length is: $length";
```

This will only strip the tags for purposes of counting. The tags never actually get lost.

**Update**

According to `webbiedave`'s suggestion it really should be

```
$theHTML='<h2>Hello!</h2>';
$length = strlen ( shtml_entity_decode(strip_tags($theHTML)) ); //Should be 6

//This will not trigger since only the text "Hello!" is only 6 chars.    
if ($length > 10) die('ERROR'); 

echo $theHTML; //Will echo full HTML, even though we checked the length without HTML.
```

Comment: You should really do `html_entity_decode(strip_tags($theHTML))` to reduce entities as well, e.g. `&quot;` becomes `"`

Comment: The length is the easy part. I want to limit them on that length... There is the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code I used earlier: `http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#92063` this function substracts the characters (fe. 0 to 1000) but leaves the HTML tags intact.